# Bootstrap5.1.3 Navigation Bar brand Text font color and size CAN NOT be modified

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am creating a main page with bootstrap navigation bar dropdown menu. I am able to display the dropdown menu and change it color in CSS. But when I tried to change the font size & color for title text of "navbar-brand", it just didn't work. No matter how big size I gave in my CSS file. it didn't change the font size and color at all. Can anyone help me out? The following is the codes:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Domine', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: 'Domine-Bold', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color:#F9FFA4;
}


.navbar-brand {
  
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Domine-Bold', serif;
  font-size: 150px; 
  font-weight: 700;  
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
  background-color:#F9FFA4;
  
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">   

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- <title>Sample</title> -->   

    <!-- Bootstrap 5.1.3 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Domine:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- https://nilsonbeds.com/ Good reference to start with-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="color-section" id="title">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <nav  class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color:#F9FFA4">

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HomeTitle</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarHome" aria-controls="navbarHome" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHome">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownNewIn" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  New In
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownNewIn">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solar Phone Charger</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penguin Aroma Diffuser</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Humidifier</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBath" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Bath Accessories
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBath">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bath Matt</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bath Towel</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownKitchen" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Kitchen Accessories
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownKitchen">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Wine Opener</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Penguin Aroma Diffuser</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

I aimed to display larger font size and change the font color for navbar-brand "HomeTitle" but it didn't happen.

Comment: Were you able to fix the color problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is happening because your bootstrap file is below the main styles.css where you add your styles and it's not reflected. this happens because the bootstrap file which is related to the framework overrides your styles. to fix this just make your main CSS file below  the bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I changed css file link location but additional problem occurred: why I only can change the font-size and font-weight but the color of font CAN NOT be changed, for example, I used the following codes to change the color:                                                                                                                    
 .navbar-brand {  color:#A85CF9;   . . . . . .;}    do you have thought about this?  Thank you very much.

Comment: That happens for sure because the bootstrap overrides your styles. to make also sure why this happens. you can use the inspection of google chrome and inspect the text that the color is not applied for it. see from why it's not changing and try to use it !important. hope that works